# Problema al buscar un metodo de Crystal Report en vb 6

Tags: vb

buenos días comunidad, necesito su ayuda con algo. voy a explicar un poco que se hizo y qué pasó.

En el pc que me asignaron en el trabajo tengo que trabajar con una aplicación que crea reportes con crystal report, hasta acá todo bienm, genero bien los pdf. Pero... hace unas semanas necesitaba editar un reporte pero no podía (cosa rara porque puedo generar bien los reportes) por lo que se pidió a soporte instalar crystal report, lo hicieron y ya puedo editar pero se cargaron el que pueda generar los reportes.

Me fijé en las referencias y claro, me faltaba la carpeta a la que hacia referencia:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\

La aplicación usa 3 .dll y estas son:

- **CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine**
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
- **CrystalDecisions.ReportSource**
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
- **CrystalDecisions.Shared**
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll

Una vez instalado por soporte me fijé que apuntaran bien las rutas a los archivos que uso y me di cuenta igual que en la etiqueta de Copy Local el Engine está en True pero no las otras, cuando compilo y ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:

> Método no encontrado:
> 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag
> CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ISCRExportOptions.get_ExportOptionsEx()'.

Las líneas de código en donde uso crystal son estas:

```
Dim rptContrato As New Contrato()
rptContrato.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, archivoContrato)
CrearArchivo(archivoContrato, baseArhivo + "Contrato.pdf", clave)
```

Este es el código de Contrato.vb

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     Este código fue generado por una herramienta.
'     Versión de runtime:4.0.30319.36543
'
'     Los cambios en este archivo podrían causar un comportamiento incorrecto y se perderán si
'     se vuelve a generar el código.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class Contrato
    Inherits ReportClass
    
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub
    
    Public Overrides Property ResourceName() As String
        Get
            Return "Contrato.rpt"
        End Get
        Set
            'Do nothing
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Public Overrides Property NewGenerator() As Boolean
        Get
            Return true
        End Get
        Set
            'Do nothing
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Public Overrides Property FullResourceName() As String
        Get
            Return "RenegExpress.Contrato.rpt"
        End Get
        Set
            'Do nothing
        End Set
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public ReadOnly Property Section1() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
        Get
            Return Me.ReportDefinition.Sections(0)
        End Get
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public ReadOnly Property Section2() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
        Get
            Return Me.ReportDefinition.Sections(1)
        End Get
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public ReadOnly Property Section3() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
        Get
            Return Me.ReportDefinition.Sections(2)
        End Get
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public ReadOnly Property Section4() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
        Get
            Return Me.ReportDefinition.Sections(3)
        End Get
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public ReadOnly Property Section5() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
        Get
            Return Me.ReportDefinition.Sections(4)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

<System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmapAttribute(GetType(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportOptions), "report.bmp")>  _
Public Class CachedContrato
    Inherits Component
    Implements ICachedReport
    
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public Overridable Property IsCacheable() As Boolean Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.IsCacheable
        Get
            Return true
        End Get
        Set
            '
        End Set
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public Overridable Property ShareDBLogonInfo() As Boolean Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.ShareDBLogonInfo
        Get
            Return false
        End Get
        Set
            '
        End Set
    End Property
    
    <Browsable(false),  _
     DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>  _
    Public Overridable Property CacheTimeOut() As System.TimeSpan Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.CacheTimeOut
        Get
            Return CachedReportConstants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
        End Get
        Set
            '
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Public Overridable Function CreateReport() As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.CreateReport
        Dim rpt As Contrato = New Contrato()
        rpt.Site = Me.Site
        Return rpt
    End Function
    
    Public Overridable Function GetCustomizedCacheKey(ByVal request As RequestContext) As String Implements CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport.GetCustomizedCacheKey
        Dim key As [String] = Nothing
        '// The following is the code used to generate the default
        '// cache key for caching report jobs in the ASP.NET Cache.
        '// Feel free to modify this code to suit your needs.
        '// Returning key == null causes the default cache key to
        '// be generated.
        '
        'key = RequestContext.BuildCompleteCacheKey(
        '    request,
        '    null,       // sReportFilename
        '    this.GetType(),
        '    this.ShareDBLogonInfo );
        Return key
    End Function
End Class
```

Esta es una aplicación que ya estaba hecha y yo he tenido que modificar algunas cosas en el código, nunca había tenido un problema con crystal report antes.

Buscando información por el error que tengo se que es algo de la instalación que hicieron o que los archivos no están para que se puedan usar, no sé que más se puede hacer. Eliminé las referencias antiguas y cree las nuevas pero aún así no me deja crear los reportes.

¿Qué se puede hacer?

Espero a alguien le haya pasado algo similar y me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Yo creo que puede ser la versión que te instalaron, revisa que versión tienes y si tiene incluida esa función o si esta descontinuada.

Comment: Hola, se que es x86 y versión 13.0.2, eso me sale en las referencias del proyecto, pero como puedo revisar que esta versión tenga esa función?